# If I query a record that doesn't exist then I will get nothing returned. I'd prefer that 0 is returned in that scenario

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here's my simple query. If I query a record that doesn't exist then I will get nothing returned. I'd prefer that 0 is returned in that scenario.
    Please help me out from this.Thanks in advance
Here's my simple query. If I query a record that doesn't exist then I will get nothing returned. I'd prefer that 0 is returned in that scenario.
    Please help me out from this.Thanks in advance

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT emp.EMP_CODE
            ,emp.EMP_NAME
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY emp.emp_code ORDER BY emp.EFFECTIVE_FROM DESC
                ) AS Row
            ,CASE 
                WHEN et.DAY = 03
                    AND et.MONTH = 02
                    AND et.YEAR = 16
                    AND et.EMP_CODE = emp.EMP_CODE
                    AND et.site_id = 21
                    THEN et.GENERAL_SHIFT
                ELSE '0'
                END AS G
            ,CASE 
                WHEN et.DAY = 03
                    AND et.MONTH = 02
                    AND et.YEAR = 16
                    AND et.EMP_CODE = emp.EMP_CODE
                    AND et.site_id = 21
                    THEN et.FIRST_SHIFT
                ELSE '0'
                END AS F
            ,CASE 
                WHEN et.DAY = 03
                    AND et.MONTH = 02
                    AND et.YEAR = 16
                    AND et.EMP_CODE = emp.EMP_CODE
                    AND et.site_id = 21
                    THEN et.SECOND_SHIFT
                ELSE '0'
                END AS S
            ,CASE 
                WHEN et.DAY = 03
                    AND et.MONTH = 02
                    AND et.YEAR = 16
                    AND et.EMP_CODE = emp.EMP_CODE
                    AND et.site_id = 21
                    THEN et.THIRD_SHIFT
                ELSE '0'
                END AS T
        FROM dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION emp
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMP_TIME_SHEET et ON emp.EMP_CODE = et.EMP_CODE
        WHERE EMP.SITE_ID = 21
            AND emp.DEPT_NAME = @DEPT_NAME
            AND emp.STATUS = 'Present'
            AND et.DAY = 03
            AND et.MONTH = 02
            AND et.YEAR = 16
        ) a
    WHERE a.Row = 1
```

Comment: Can you show us what your current output looks like?

Comment: What you want doesn't make sense. You are selecting a records set not a scalar value. Do you want a records with all field set to Zero?

Comment: EMP_CODE EMP_NAME G F S T

Comment: YES IF VALUE IS NOT THEIR SET TO ZERO

Comment: In what context do you process the results of this query?

Comment: using day,month,year value is find record then display that record otherwise display zero

Comment: Scalar varibles are added in my code  help me out how to to modify this query

Comment: Why not handle this in the presentation layer? If the resultset is empty, display a line with zeros, otherwise display the resultset... AFAICS there's no need to handle this in the database layer.

Comment: Ok Thank Very Much For Suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `ISNULL` operator for this task.
What `ISNULL` allows you to do is to check if a particular value in a SQL operation is `NULL` and allows you to return any custom value in it's place. The non-NULL values are unaffected. It works something like this:

```
SELECT Name, ISNULL(Department, 'Unassigned')
FROM [dbo].[Employee]
```

What this does is, for any employee who has a `NULL` field in the department column, the output table shows the Department column value as Unassigned.
You can also use the entire SQL query as an input too.

```
SELECT ISNULL( (SELECT MAX(Score) FROM [dbo].[Students]), 'Unchecked')
```

In this case if the max score from the student table is `NULL` we receive the output as Unchecked. 
You can find detailed documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

Hope this helps.